# Powershell | Show Tomcat-Restart-Process as a progress bar

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

There are four Tomcat services. I would like to restart it and display the status as a progress bar. Stopping 4 times and starting 4 times would be a total of 8 steps. I've tried the following, but unfortunately it doesn't give the expected result. I have no idea how to do it either. Could anyone help me, please?

```
        for ($i = 1; (Get-Service -DisplayName *tomcat*).Count -le 5; $i++ )
    {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i
        Get-Service -DisplayNAme *tomcat* | stop-service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    }

for ($i = 1; (Get-Service -DisplayName *tomcat*).Count -le 5; $i++ )
    {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i
        Get-Service -DisplayNAme *tomcat* | start-service -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why first a loop to stop the services and then another loop to start them up again?
There is also a [Restart-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service) cmdlet that stops and then starts a service, so with that you only need one loop.
Also, if you capture the result of the `Get-Service` cmdlet in a variable, you won't have to do that over and over again:

```
# the @() ensures the result is an array so we can use its .Count property
$tomcat = @(Get-Service -DisplayName *tomcat* )

for ($i = 1; $i -le $tomcat.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Restarting Tomcat service" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i
    $tomcat[$i -1] | Restart-Service -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Two questions:  #### 1. How can I let display the current tomcat service. $tomcat[$i] lists all services at once. #### 2. Progressbar shows 1% per restart process. So in the end I got 4% instead of 100%. I thought '($i*25)% complete:' would work. But it doesn't. How can I do it?